# Dojo- domAttr.set not working in IE

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I want to set the style attribute to the div tag in dojo 1.8.I have used the following code.

```javascript
    require([
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
        "dojo/store/JsonRest",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-attr"
    ], function (request, Memory, OnDemandGrid,JsonRest,dom,domAttr) {
            jsonstore = new JsonRest({target: url,idProperty: "srno"});
            grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                store: jsonstore,
                columns: Layout,
                minRowsPerPage : 40,
                maxRowsPerPage : 40,
                keepScrollPosition : true,
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                noDataMessage: "No results found."
            }, "grid");
            domAttr.set(dom.byId("grid"),"style","height:250px");
            grid.startup();
        });
```

It works fine with firefox.In IE,the below code is not working

```
        domAttr.set(dom.byId("grid"),"style","height:250px");
```

I put alert and verified.

```
         alert(domAttr.get(dom.byId("grid"),"style")
```

In firefox ,it is showing height:250px . In IE it is null.
Can someone tell me how to make domAttr.set work in IE as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dojo/dom-style instead of dom-Attr

```
require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle){
 domStyle.set("someNode", "width", "100px");
});
```

Here's the link to the ref : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-style.html#dojo-dom-style

Regards, Miriam